# Where can I download a clean ksecdd.sys, or how do I extract ksecdd.sys from the installation media?

Tags: windows-7, boot

For the record, I have a dual boot installation of Windows and Linux, and I am currently booted into Linux.

After updating Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit), the operating system will no longer boot, quoting that `ksecdd.sys` is missing or corrupted.  I cannot get into safe mode to run the system file checker either, and because of the dual boot configuration of the system, the boot repair from an installation disk does not correctly operate and cannot fix the issue.  After turning on the system from the updates, chkdisk ran and fixed multiple filesystem issues.  After that rebooted, the error about `ksecdd.sys` appeared.

I have access to the C:\ partition of the system (via Linux) and checked the file.  Somehow, chkdisk fixed the filesystem issues, but in the process, corrupted `ksecdd.sys` and replaced it with a 0-bytesize file.

Is there anywhere I can download a good copy of the file, or any way I can get the good copy of the file off the installation disk, in order to replace the 0-bytes file that chkdisk broke, and make my system boot again?  I do not want to do a repair installation as I do not have backup media that are of sufficient size  to hold the files I need to back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not solve this question using the installation disk.

I was able to install Windows to a virtual machine inside my Linux installation.  From there, I copied out the `ksecdd.sys` file and stored it on external media able to be read by the VM.

From there, I copied the good ksecdd.sys file into the system directory for the impacted system and was able to restore the boot system.

Something in the latest Microsoft updates broke the ksecdd.sys file and the file structure of the disk, which is probably what caused this issue.

Comment: you can use 7zip to extract files from a Windows DVD: http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/

Comment: @magicandre1981 if you can write that as an answer, and include the steps in the answer itself, as well as that link, then I'll give you an upvote and the "Accepted Answer", I just put this answer here to indicate I took a long method to solve the issue.  (And Windows boots fine with the replacement ksecdd.sys :D)

Answer (score -1):

Did you know about the Repair Function on the Windows installation cd/dvd?

insert cd/dvd on the first screen in the undrr right corner there should be somthing about repair windows. this will reinstall all windows drivers and system files. (registry and personal files will stay)

Comment: Knew about it.  tried it.  It failed because of the dual boot configuration.  Which is why I asked how to get a clean copy of the system file manually from the disk.  I took a long method to get it though, but the link magicandre gave me pointed out how to manually extract the file from the disk so now I have a clean copy of the files in case I need them in the future.